# Bootstrap $modal window backdrop clears elements in the screen

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem that is happening in my app and I don´t really know how to replicate here as a simplified version, so I ask this in case someone has an idea on what might be happening.

I have an SPA which loads different views during the navigation. In one of those views I click on an element in the screen and this opens a modal window. I'm using bootstrap $modal to do this. The problem is that when the modal window appears everything else from the view behing dissapears. Only the elements outside the view in the SPA remain.

Any ideas? I get no errors in the console. I'm guessing it's related to the processing in angular, maybe the modal window is processed before the view and stops when the window is displayed? Also, if I press on the screen to close the window, everything comes back.

EDIT: I can provide a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7UDTJeysD2BMIyCZyajJ?p=preview) that works fine as the image underneath the modal window does not dissapear, so not very helpful I'm afraid.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'myApp'])

.config(['$routeProvider', 
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/index', {
                template: '<my-dir></my-dir>',
                controller: 'myCtrl'
            }).
          otherwise({
                template: '<my-dir></my-dir>',
                controller: 'myCtrl'
          });
}]);

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.actions = [
    {'x':50,'y':40,'time':'02:00','period':'1','name':'name1'},
    {'x':50,'y':60,'time':'02:00','period':'2','name':'name2'},
    {'x':50,'y':80,'time':'02:00','period':'3','name':'name3'}
  ]

}])

.directive("myDir", ['$compile', '$modal', function($compile, $modal){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) { 

      for (var i = 0; i < scope.actions.length; i++) {
        var circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
            circle.setAttribute('cx', scope.actions[i].x);
            circle.setAttribute('cy', scope.actions[i].y);
            circle.setAttribute('r', 5);            
        circle.setAttribute('ng-click', 'open(' + i + ')');
        element.append(circle);
      }
      $compile(element)(scope);
    },
    controller: function($scope) {              
          $scope.open = function (idx) {                    
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          windowClass: 'center-modal',
          templateUrl: 'modalWindow.html',
          controller: 'myDirCtrl',
          resolve: {
                      action: function() {
                        return $scope.actions[idx];
                      }
          }
        });
        };              
        },
    template:'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400"><image x="0" y="0" width="400" height="200" xlink:href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"/></svg>'
  }
}])

.controller('myDirCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, action) {
        $scope.action = action;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out the problem.

I found out that this issue was happening because of a .css file in my application. I had defined a height for my body and apparently when the modal window is opened the element is created inside the body, and was marking everything else with `overflow: hidden`.

I removed the height in my html body and everything came back.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide some code how you are using the $modal?

I would recommed using Angular-UI as a Bootstrap Implementation.
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

They work a lot better in the Angular World.

Hope this can help you !

Edit:

try to define your modal like this :

```
$scope.openmodal = function () {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
templateUrl :"./Pathtoexternalmodalhere",
controller :"yourcontroller"
})
};
```

At least this works well with my apps!

Comment: I edited the description. I know it's not very helpful like this. I'm still trying to replicate my problem in plunker.

Comment: No, in my original code I'm already using templateUrl and a controller for my modalInstance and the problem is also happening. I think it's not really related to the configuration of the modal window but to the way angular works in terms of views and SPAs.